# How to float an element to the right with inline display block while maintaining a centered vertical sibling?

Tags: css, css-float, inline, display

Hi I'm currently trying to float my icon element to the right, while maintaining how its centered vertically next to its sibling element. I know `float` and `display: inline-block` can't coexist with each other. I've already tried using `direction: rtl` and `text-align: right` for my icon. I also don't want to hardcode by using pixels with margins/paddings, since I want this to be mobile-responsive. Are there any ideas?

Here's what the HTML would look like:

```
<span class='container'>
  <p class='text'>Here is a lot of text and it is meant to overflow.</p>
  <icon class='caret'></icon>
</span>
```

Here's my current CSS:

```
.text{
  width: 340px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.caret{
  color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  //float: right; //doesn't work

}
```

Photo Example of Desired Result: [image]

Comment: make the container inline-flex and then you can easily do this using space-between

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19026884/8620333